# Proper way to git(?) a project with multiple files and multiple different environment builds

Tags: git

**Sorry if questions like this is not intended for this forum**

We are a group of 8 people with different OS (linux, osx, windows). We are being tasked to continue develop an app (react native). How should we best work with git?

Right now we are thinking of having one `master` branch for stable releases and one `dev` branch which we are pushing our "day to day" code to.

The problem we are having is that the files that are generated after the build is different from one environment to the other. And we cant find a good pattern to use when gitignoring (even while using third part apps like `www.gitignore.io`.

One thing that we are considering is that each have their own `dev` branch like `dev/bob`, `dev/alice` etc.. Where the branch is a stable environment for the user, and we `rebase` the main `dev` branch after a feature is complete.

We are all very new with working in a larger group and project. What are the branch standard to a problem like this? What can we do to solve it?

Comment: Usually in non-monoculture setups you put your exclusion patterns in your own ignore files (see the git config docs for `core.excludesfile`, set that in your per-user `--global` config).  It's only when the build system setup itself is being tracked that you also track the exclude patterns for its intermediate products.

Comment: @jthill The problem then is which files should we ignore? We are uncertain of which are being built and which are important for the build

Comment: @vonhact simple: keep ignoring more and more file until the build fails ;)

Comment: @VonC Yeah that basically what we did, one 2 hours later we figured that it was a bad idea haha!